# How do I balance out Refinement bonuses for Thaumaturgy/Enchantment?

Tags: dresden-files

My character is an artificer focused full-wizard (Submerged). She has an item of Power that contains three refinements. I read in Your Story that refinements have to be stacked like skills, but what does that mean for Thaumaturgy? Do I need to spread bonuses between Power and Uses of Enchanted Items or do I need to spread them across the Thaumaturgy skills?

Comment: Could you clarify what you do mean under "item of Power that contains three refinements"? Items of power afaik, can't containt refinements. Refinement is a wizard specialization upgrade.

Comment: Refinement is listed as a Supernatural Power (like Supernatural Toughness etc) with a refresh cost of 1. Item of Power gives you a one-time discount on powers bought with refresh, so I bought Refinement three times and (because my item is a large sword) got a two point discount.

Comment: I wasn't expecting this. Kudos for approach.

Comment: I edited the word 'enchantment' to be 'artificer' because enchantment is not used in the sense of 'enchanting equipment to be stronger' but as charming a target in the context of DFPRG (ie her beauty was enchanting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only specialization part of refinement should be split and arranged in columns. Enchanted items part is a fully separated from specialization and don't need any column like structure (but there is crafting specialization that allow you to get additional "Enchanted Item slot" effect and those need to be arranged in columns).

**Thaumaturgy specialization**

Some Example of Thaumaturgy types from YS:

- Summoning and Binding
- Wards
- Crafting
- Transformation and Disruption
- Transportation and Wordwalking
- Necromancy
- Ectomancy
- Biomancy
- and many more (you can create new if you so desire)

Each type (except Crafting) have a 'standard' complexity/control specialization split. Crafting split to frequency/power (see YS.280 for additional information on crafting). Specialization can be only taken in columns (or pyramid), Specialization type (Wards, Ectomancy) or sub-type (complexity/control) doesn't matter, only structure. 
So for example we can have:

```
+2 | Wards (Complexity)
+1 | Divination (Control)
```

Now we can spend 3 specialization points and get:

```
+2 | Wards (Complexity)  , Crafting (Frequency)
+1 | Divination (Control), Pyromancy (Complexity)
```

For example, Grevane [p.155 OW] thaumaturgy specializations written in columns will looks like:

```
+2 | Necromancy (Control), Necromancy (Complexity)
+1 | Summoning (Control) , Divination (Control)   , Summoning(Complexity), Divination (Complexity)
```

**Enchanted Items and Thaumaturgy Crafting specialization.**

Let's say we have +3 Lore, 2 Enchanted item slots and specialization in thaumaturgy crafting like this:

```
+2 | Crafting (Frequency)
+1 | Crafting (Strength)
```

This configuration allow us to create item 
+3 1 time per session (from Lore), which become +4 effect 3 times per session after adding our specialization bonuses, and we can increase it further by using our additional Enchanted Item slot (see p.280 YS for Enchanted Item slots modifications).

Answer (score 1):

Crafting Strength / Frequency are refinement specializations like any other refinement.  They must follow the column rules, like any other refinement.  So yes, you'll probably need other refinements in other thaumaturgy fields to push them to any real height.